# IRC protocol message formatting

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, irc

I've been searching for a while, but I can't seem to find the message formatting of the IRC protocol. For example, if I wanted to enter a channel, the client might send "enter channelname nick" or something along those lines. Does anyone know?

Comment: Add more tags for better results.

Comment: Probably more detail than you need, but this is the official document: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1459.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the RFC: http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/rfc.html

Or open your favorite IRC client and use a sniffer to see what the incoming/outgoing packets look like.

I'm guessing you are asking how to join a channel:

http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/chapter4.html#c4_2_1

You simply send:  `JOIN #channel\r\n`